# Why does GA tracking code start with two (instead of one) .push commands?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-analytics

I'm trying to understand how Google Analytics works and one thing I started to wonder is why they don't replace

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

with `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y','_trackPageview']);`

I mean, why **two** (rather than one or three) lines for **three** array elements? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It would be: `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y'], ['_trackPageview']);`

Comment: Then _qaq is an array consisting of arrays, right?

Comment: Initially `_gaq` is an array, but when the `ga.js` code loads, it's replaced by an object with a `push` method like an array. The array that's pushed onto `_gaq` contains a function name  & arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replace the 2 push statement with a single one and it will provide the same functionality

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X'], ['_trackPageview']);
```

The 2 push statements do different roles:

1,The first once sets the **web property ID** for the tracking object. This means all further push statements to the same queue will be sent to the same GA property (tracking ID).

2,The second push **tracks a pageview** using the above tracking object and is typically the first GA functionality required when you load analytics in any webpage. 
Now you can send further tracking data to your GA account with the already created tracking object and you just need to invoke the corresponding push statements like below:

-event tracking

```
<button onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'button3', 'clicked'])"/><button>
```

- ecommerce tracking, etc

  _gaq.push(['_addTrans', transactionId, affiliation, total, tax, shipping, city, state, country]);

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But there MUST be some reason why the guys at Google don't just put it on one line like you did, right?